# Assembly - Trying to move byte to memory not working

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I am trying to modify a string which is stored in memory by changing a byte in it. I'm using movb to this but for some reason, the byte at the given memory location is not changing.

On gdb debugger:

> 14             movb %al, (%r10) # next instr
>   (gdb) print /d $al
>   $4 = 0
>   (gdb) print /c *$r10
>   $5 = 47 '/'
>   (gdb) s
>   16              mov $59, %rax
>   (gdb) print /c *$r10
>   $6 = 47 '/'

The code is just:

```
.globl _start
.text

_start:
        call chamaexecve
        variaveis:
            .asciz "/bin/bashABBBBCCCC"


    chamaexecve: 

        pop %r10
        xor %rax, %rax
        movb %al, (%r10) # problem happening here

        mov $59, %rax
        mov %rsi, %rdi
        mov $0, %rsi
        mov $0, %rdx

        syscall
```

And it is being compiled with `as -gstabs -o shellf.o shellf.s` - `ld -N -z execstack  -o shellf shellf.o`

**Edit** To be sure I wasn't making any mistake I deleted the executable and recompiled. The error persists. Another thing I noticed is that if I add a line `movb $'r', %al` before moving %al to memory, so the `'r'` is normally printed on memory but for some reason it is not working with the `$0` value.

I'm running this on a Linux Mint 18.1 "Serena" rolling release, gnu assembler 2.26.1. Here is a print using `x/i $rip` to show the current instruction:

[image]

**Edit2**:
After changing break to tbreak and s to si, I saw it changing from '/' to '\000' finally. So what could be the problem after all s/break/gdb getting messed up?

> (gdb) tb 14
>   Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4000cd: file shellf.s, line 14.
>   (gdb) run
>   Starting program: /home/fabio/criação/nasm-tutorial/shellf 
>   
>   Temporary breakpoint 1, chamaexecve () at shellf.s:14
>   14              movb %al, (%r10)
>   (gdb) si
>   16              mov $59, %rax
>   (gdb) print /c *$rsi
>   Cannot access memory at address 0x0
>   (gdb) print /c *$r10
>   $1 = 0 '\000'
>   (gdb)

Comment: Are you sure you are running the binary you just compiled? Works fine here, as it should. +1 for using a debugger though :) Also check actual instruction with `x/i $rip` in case debug info is mismatched.

Comment: I checked again with `x/i $rip` and the instruction was aligned. To make sure it was the right binary I removed the anterior. I also noticed that if I added `movb $'r', %al` the `r` was moved to memory but not if %al = 0. Btw, you always answer my questions, thank you very much ^^

Comment: I might be missing something here, but why do you think that r10 is pointing to variaveis or any valid memory for that matter?

Comment: @NickApperson because of the `call`+`pop` trick (which is of course not needed in 64 bit, but that's a different matter).

Comment: Ah right, forgot about that. It seems like it might generate a sigsegv or sigbus if the memory flags aren't set correctly, as in the memory may be read/exec (not writable). I've seen GDB ignore this before and silence the error.

Comment: To debug, you might try reading the memory after written with movzx (%r10), %eax and then reading the return value from the console with $? to check. It may be an artifact of gdb. They are rare, but do exist.

Comment: He used the `s` command (single step) which relies on debug info being correct so I'd be happier to see `si` being used and the output of `x/i $rip` which he also claims is fine. Furthermore, writing something else than a zero is reported to work, I can't think of any reason why writing a zero should then fail.

Comment: @Jester I suspect too that there is likely some disconnect between the debug info and where it thinks each line maps to an instruction.

Comment: This warning is just because I was running the `list` command and it reached the end of the text. I tried compiling and debugging with gdwarf-2 but the behavior was the same...

Comment: [Works fine here](http://imgur.com/a/4rQlE), no idea what could be wrong. What happens if you change it to `rsi` (because that's what you use later in the syscall) and run it through `strace` instead of `gdb`? What file name do you see in the first argument for the `execve` call?

Comment: I think what is happening is that GDB is getting messed up with self modifying code. Rather than use `break 14` what if you make it a temporary break with `tbreak 14`.

Comment: Given that these seems to work in some environments (Debian Jessie) and not in others (your environment and Ubuntu 16.04) you might want to address this issue with the GDB bug tracking system. See this link to make a report: https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/  . I can only guess that a GDB bug and/or the Linux environment you are running in is somehow interfering with proper operation. It is possible it may be expected behavior (and they have a work around) or they find it to be a bug. I was able to confirm this behaviour on Ubuntu 16.04 which Linux Mint 18.1 is based on.

Answer (score 0):

The .text section of a program is read only, if you would like to modify the string you'll want to place it in the .data section.

Comment: The OP compiled with `ld -N` which makes the text and data sections read/write.  If this was the problem, the GDB output would include SIGSEGV, but that's not what happens.  Read the comments and the update: using `s` instead of `si` was leading to GDB not showing stuff correctly.